What is name of SOT23-5 IC which is written "601Km" on its surface?
I have T12-952 Soldering Station which is not able to display any screen. But when I power on it, iron become hot.
I desolder some components to check whether it have been faulty or not, but when I tried to desolder an IC which is written "601Km" on the surface, I broke leftmost pin like attached photos.



I use Mini Drill in order to peel off plastic surface but I cannot found copper sheet which is supposed to be pin3.
What is name of IC which is written "601Km" on the surface?
And Is there any PDF datasheet about this IC?

This is a 3PEAK TP56001-TR. It is an op amp.

Picture from device datasheet linked above.

Picture from reseller LCSC and it can be found here.
I was able to find the device by searching on Google Images, "601 SOT23-5", then I saw a picture of the device that looked very similar to the chip marking from your original picture and that's how I was able to find the part number to confirm.

Thank you very much for reply! I found taobao link that is very similar to this SOT23 IC. https://gw.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/2226931397/O1CN01Kz5lf71MBs69u1nvf_!!2226931397.jpg_Q75.jpg_.webp

By the way Is there any infomation about data code of  TP6001-TR? I purchased T12-952 Soldering Station three years ago,So I want to confirm that what "Km" stand for in order to figure out when this TP6001-TR was manufactured...

@bshi02 You're welcome! In the picture that I have above, it says that the Km is part of the date code. Only the chip supplier will be able to interpret that. It's really only for their sake so if anything goes wrong, they can identify a more probable root cause of why it failed.

A few days ago, I fianlly received  3PEAK TP6001-TR. and I narrowly soldered it to PCB of  T12-952 Soldering Station. To fix no display problem, I followed below reddit tutorial and Now it display clear screen as it used to be :) https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/r0fguj/new_quicko_t12942_display_off/
